# VScode: How stop a download file from Remote SSH?

Tags: vscode-remote-ssh

I'm trying to stop a download from a remote server connected with Remote SSH.
Can't find any button to stop, just closing the VScode.

[Download Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDanN.png)

trying to stop the download, but i cant find a simply way to stop the download

Comment: I can't see any user friendly way, though [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111578#issuecomment-1832612872) on an GitHub issue suggests reloading the window works, and that's slightly less disruptive than closing the entire program.